# How to implement Caching a datatable for auto complete in C#?

Tags: caching, autocomplete, datatable

I am trying to cache my datatable for autocomplete. Firstly I create a datatable and fill it with content from my database. Then when I try to cache the datatable I get an execution error which implies "using System.Runtime.Caching;" statement is wrong. 
I added system.runtime.caching reference to the project. I didn't understand why did I get this error.

Furtermore, if I delete that statement I get an exception that says "Cache is not available".

Im new with caching and feel free to explain how this thing is done. Until now i am sending queries to db for every search in autoComplete box. I would like to use caching in order to speed things up. Here is my code:

```
    _Default obj = new _Default();
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=db; Initial Catalog=cat;Integrated Security=True");
    con.Open();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from City", con);
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    da.Fill(dt);
    obj.Cache["Cache"] = dt;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm also new to DataCaching, but have find solution that works well for me. Here is my working example:

```
private DataContext db = new DataContext();

    public List<Trip> GetAll()
    {
        string key = "TripGetAll1";
        var cac = HttpRuntime.Cache[key] as List<Trip>;
        if (cac == null)
        {
            cac = db.Trip.Include(x => x.Hands)
                            .Include(x => x.TransferPoints)
                            .Include(x => x.Requests)
                            .Include(x => x.Vehicle)
                            .Include(x => x.Crew)
                            .Include(x => x.ServiceType)
                            .Where(x => x.StornoBy == null)
                            .ToList();
            HttpRuntime.Cache.Insert(key, cac, null,
                DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ShortCache"].StringToInt()), TimeSpan.Zero);
        }
        return cac;
    }
```

This part

```
System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ShortCache"].StringToInt()
```

is taking form web.config duration (in development and later to be easier adjusted in production). And **StringToInt()** is my extension, so ignore that.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I understand how you insert and take data from cache.
I solved the execution error by the way. I wrote system.web.caching instead of system.runtime.caching.